# Unable to send from alphanumeric sender using Liquid syntax (via Customer.io)

Tags: twilio

I am trying to dynamically choose my Twilio sender using Liquid syntax as described in the Customer.io [documentation](https://www.customer.io/docs/twilio/#using-liquid-to-determine-your-sender-id).

My Liquid syntax (for the purpose of *Hello, World*) is:

```
{% if customer.first_name == "Blair" %} X-Y {% endif %}
```

I am getting the following error message when trying to use anything other than a valid phone number:

```
The 'From' number X is not a valid phone number, shortcode, or alphanumeric sender ID.
```

Sending from an alphanumeric sender works when not using Liquid. My Twilio account's messaging settings have alphanumeric sending enabled. I am not attempting to send messages to a country that does not support alphanumeric senders (e.g., USA).

### Note

- I do not currently have enough reputation to create a new `customer.io` tag
- I have asked Customer.io's support team for help and am currently awaiting a response (I'm not sure on which side the misconfiguration/lack of feature/bug lies)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, OK, so Twilio's [documentation on Error 21212](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21212) is actually pretty clear:

> Twilio accepts phone numbers in E.164 format (i.e. "+1 format"), 10-digit US and Canadian numbers with any combination of non-digit separators, or Alphanumeric Sender IDs (SMS only) with up to 11 alphanumeric characters [a-zA-Z0-9].

Hence, alphanumeric senders cannot contain hyphens, so the error message I am getting is in line with the documentation.

However, I am still not sure as to why I am able to use senders with hyphens or whitespace in Customer.io when entering directly in the "Sender ID" field but not when chosen dynamically using Liquid syntax…

Comment: Is Customer.io stripping the hyphen/whitespace for you?

Comment: @philnash not in any way that is obvious to me… and, previously, the more out-of-the-box configuration allowed me to successfully send messages with a sender ID that included whitespace (and appeared as such on my mobile phone)—not sure how this was allowed!

Comment: I think whitespace works on occasion and depends on the network/device. But hyphens don’t work. To be safe, I’d avoid both.

Comment: @philnash yep, planning on steering clear going forward. Thank you for the help!